# MODX Revo: как вывести на экран содержимое pdoMenu как строку? Для отладки

Tags: modx, отладка, revo

Есть код:

```
[[pdoMenu?
            &parents=`0`
            &level=`1`
        ]]
```

Как просмотреть, что там есть в виде строки кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некоторые сниппеты выведут результат работы на страницу, если указать пустой шаблон, будет так:

```
[[pdoMenu?
&parents=`0`
&level=`1`
&tpl=``
]]
```

Comment: Я ахренел! Там кода километр вышло ))))

Comment: =) Как-нибудь с bitrix поработайте